# How to define a schema for the mult nested json objects in Normalizr using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have a scenario where my json grows dynamically
sample json:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Chapter first',
    list: [{
      id: 11,
      title: 'Chapter Child 1'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Books Parent',
    list: [{
      id: 2.1,
      title: 'Book Child 1'
    }]
  }
```

]

List attribute inside object keeps on growing.

For Example another scenario:

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Chapter first',
    list: [{
      id: 11,
      title: 'Chapter Child 1',
      list: [{
        id: 111,
        title: 'Chapter Child 2',
        list:[{
            id: 1111,
            title: 'Chapter Child 1',
            list: [{
              id: 1112,
              title: 'Chapter Child 2'
            }, {
              id: 1132,
              title: 'Chapter Child 3'
            }]
            }, {
              id: 1133,
              title: 'Chapter Child 3'
            }]
    }]
  }
```

When i seen the redux documentation they mentioned for nested objects use normalizr.
But how to design common normalize pattern for above two scenarios?

Comment: do you mean this ? http://www.webpackbin.com/4J_LqAB1z

Comment: Right.. Thanks alot . 
Another query 
1) How to iterate in the react for rendering the normalized data. 
2) Whether its possible to swap the data. example id:1133 should be removed and moved above id:1132

Comment: Can you please explain too how the schema should be defined for multiple combinations